# Heroku / Rails: can't set path to vendorized dependencies

Tags: c++, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, boost

I've got a set of libs/headers/binaries that are used to build some gems in my app (specifically Boost and SWIG). I've pre-built everything on a cedar-14 docker image and put it all in my vendor directory, so I have "vendor/swig" and "vendor/lib/boost" etc. I've tried setting paths with both heroku config:set and by making a paths.sh file in .profile.d as recommended in the documentation but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is you can't, you need to make a buildpack.